# How to change the size of the ESP32's UART-TX-FIFO

Tags: esp32

Configuration of the ESP32's UART_MEM_CONF_REG register does not change the size of the uart TX FIFO as expected.

I'm trying to change the size of UART0's TX FIFO o 512 Bytes.

The FIFO's size (in byte) can be set in UART_MEM_CONF_REG configuring bits 7 to bit 10. (ESP32 TRM V4.0, page 364)
This register is 0x88 by default: 128 Byte TX FIFO and 128 byte RX FIFO. So bit 7 = 1 sets 128 Byte TX FIFO size.

Unfortunately there is no info how to set Bits 7, 8,9, and 10 to change the FIFO size. My first idea was to set bit 8 for 256 bytes size, bit 9 for 512 bytes and bit 10 to 1024 bytes. I intend to use UART0 only, so there's no problem with the other UART's FIFO size.

I tried the following lines:

```
// Create a byte pattern to send
char buffer[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) buffer[i] = i;

// f.e.set bit 8 for (maybe??) 256 bytes TX FIFO size, other configurations has been tested as well
WRITE_PERI_REG(UART_MEM_CONF_REG(uart_num),0x108);

// Start uart driver, no event queue, no TX ringbuffer
uart_driver_install(uart_num, UART_BUF_SIZE, 0, 0, NULL, 0);

// send 256 bytes from a buffer
uart_tx_chars(uart_num, (const char*)buffer, 256);
// but only 128 bytes are sent
```

At least I expected some change of the TX-FIFO size. But that's not working. The transmission ends after 128 bytes are sent out - no matter how I set the bits 7 to 10 in the UART_MEM_CONF_REG.

What's wrong, what did I miss?

Comment: uart_tx_chars() returns early if the FIFO is full. You should use uart_write_bytes(), which will block until all data has been committed to the TX FIFO.